# Make animation with multiple external data files

Tags: import, animation, data-acquisition

I am currently solving PDEs for a discrete vector field with C++.
The output at a time t is an array where each row represents a site and there are 6 columns, the first 3 give the position of the site and the last 3 give the components of the vector in that site.

I already managed to pick one file and plot it so that I get a nice visualization.

What I want to do now is to pick several data sets, A_0 to A_100, and make an animation with it.

This is the code I have:

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
mmm = ReadList["A_49.txt", Number, RecordLists -> True];

pos = Table[{mmm[[i, 1]], mmm[[i, 2]], mmm[[i, 3]]}, {i, 1, Length[mmm]}];
b = Table[{mmm[[i, 4]], mmm[[i, 5]], mmm[[i, 6]]}, {i, 1, Length[mmm]}];

figure = Table[arrow[pos[[i]], b[[i]], ColorData["DarkRainbow"]
         [(b[[i]].{0,0,1} + 1)/2]], {i, 1, Length[pos]}];

Show[figure, Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {0, 0, 10}]
```

Sorry if this is easy, I'm new to both animations and Mathematica.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Thanks bbgodfrey! I just took the tour.
I liked the simplicity and the privileges-system. I'll make my best to become a useful member of the community.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a function that plots the content of a file like this:

```
plot[file_] := Module[{mmm, figure, pos, b},
    mmm = ReadList[NotebookDirectory[] <> file, Number, RecordLists -> True];
    (* ... the rest of your code. *)
]
```

To make an animation you have to first create a list with all the "frames", then you can display it with `ListAnimate` or export it as a gif using `Export`.

```
frames = plot / @ Table["A_" <> ToString@i <> ".txt", {i, 0, 100}];
ListAnimate[frames]
```

Comment: Hey @pickett, thanks for your answer, but it gives me an error:
`StringJoin::string: "String expected at position 2 in A_ <> 0 <> .txt"

Comment: @FelipeP. My mistake, fixed it.